# how to build function that multiply matrices created via struct in C

Tags: c, matrix

I am supposed to build a matrix_mul function that display the result of a multiplication between two matrices that were created via a struct. My problem is, my function does not multiply the value inside the matrices instead it return an interger.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{

   int rows;
   int cols;
   int **data;

} matrix;


matrix matrix_mul(int **a, int **b){

 int rowA=(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
 int colA=(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0][0]))/rowA;

 int rowB=(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]));
 int colB=(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0][0]))/rowB;

 int i, j, **mulMatrix;

 if(colA != rowB)
  printf("error: cannot multiply matrices");

 else{
        int i, j, k;

        mulMatrix = (int **)malloc(rowA * sizeof(int *));
        for(i=0; i<rowA; i++)
           mulMatrix[i] = (int *)malloc(colB * sizeof(int));

       for(i=0; i<rowA; ++i){
         for(j=0; j<colB; ++j){
           for(k=0; k<colA; ++k)
           {
           mulMatrix[i][j]+= a[i][k] * b[k][j];       
           }
         }
       }
 }
  printf("Matrix: \n\n");

  for(i=0; i< rowA; i++){

   for(j=0; j< colB; j++){

      printf("%d   ", mulMatrix[i][j]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");
 }


}


int main()
{

 int i, j;

 matrix a, b;

 printf("matrix1 - enter number of rows and cols: ");
 scanf("%d %d", &a.rows, &a.cols);

 a.data = (int **)malloc(a.rows * sizeof(int *));

 printf("enter matrix values: ");

  for(i=0; i<a.rows; i++){

   a.data[i] = (int *)malloc(a.cols * sizeof(int));

   for(j=0; j<a.cols; j++){

      scanf("%d", &a.data[i][j]);
   }
  }


 printf("matrix2 - enter number of rows and cols: ");
 scanf("%d %d", &b.rows, &b.cols);

 b.data = (int **)malloc(b.rows * sizeof(int *));

 printf("enter matrix values: ");

  for(i=0; i<b.rows; i++){

    b.data[i] = (int *)malloc(b.cols * sizeof(int));

   for(j=0; j<b.cols; j++){

      scanf("%d", &b.data[i][j]);
   }
 }

 matrix_mul(a.data, b.data);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `matrix matrix_mul(int **a, int **b){` --> `matrix *matrix_mul(matrix *a, matrix *b){` also `sizeof(a)` is pointer size and `matrix_mul` is not return value. or type of return change to void.

Comment: so...many...problems...with...code. `Sizeof(T*)==sizeof(size_t)` (on most systems), so `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` will almost alwyas be 1, and sizeof(a)/sizeo(a[0][0]) will be 1 on 32 bit machines and 2 on 64 bit machines (usually). Basic debugging would have shown you this, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines

```
int rowA=(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
int colA=(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0][0]))/rowA;
```

won't give you the results you are looking for.

`sizeof(a)` is `sizeof(int**)` and `sizeof(a[0])` is `sizeof(int*)`. Since pointers are usually of the same size, `rowA` will be always set to `1`. `colA` will be set to `sizeof(int**)/sizeof(int)`, which is a constant value. Once again, it's not the value you are hoping to get.

You should pass the `matrix` objects, `a` and `b` to `matrix_mul`. That'll give you the size of the matrices to use for multiplying them.

```
matrix matrix_mul(matrix a, matrix b){
```

Of course, you need to modify the implementation accordingly.